# How can I make the waveform in sequencer bigger?

Tags: interface, video-sequence-editor, audio

[image]

I am using the alpha if that makes any difference, it shouldn't. I looked under view already and I don't see any relevant options, I also tried to box select the audio track and resize with "S" but its not working. As you can see I can barely see the waveform can someone please help me?

Comment: Hold CTRL+MMB and pull-up mouse on Y axis (screen Y). This will stretch working area, pulling down will shrink it. That is for Win system.

Comment: Thanks this worked, if you want to post that as the answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From official manual:

[Navigating — Blender Manual 2.80](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/video_editing/sequencer/navigating.html)

> **Use these shortcuts to adjust the sequence area of the VSE:**
>
> (...)
>
> - Scale View: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>MMB</kbd> and drag up/down (vertical scale) or left/right (horizontal scale).
> - Scale View Vertically: drag on the circles on the vertical scrollbar.
> - Scale View Horizontally: drag on the circles on the horizontal scrollbar.